# How can I use SqlBulkCopy from Entity Framework database connection in unknown state

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a static helper method for bulk inserting Entity Framework objects. It works and my unit tests pass but it looks wrong and I can't help but think there must be a better way to do it.

```
public static void BulkInsert<T>(Entities db, IList<T> list)
{
    SqlTransaction transaction =  db.Database.CurrentTransaction != null ? db.Database.CurrentTransaction.UnderlyingTransaction as SqlTransaction : null;

    if (db.Database.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        db.Database.Connection.Open();
    }

    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy((db.Database.Connection) as SqlConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, transaction))
    {
        //fill a datatable and write to server, this bit works
    }
}
```

It could be called inside a `DbContextTransaction` and/or the `DbContext.Database` might have done something already so the connection might be open. If you don't explicitly open the connection before creating the bulk copy you get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: WriteToServer requires an open and available Connection

which is odd, I'd have thought that `sqlBulkCopy` would have opened the connection if it had to.

So my question is am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used your approach successfully myself.
My feeling is that you should close it again if you opened it.

I would additionally let `SqlBulkCopy` handle the transaction itself. I don't think enlisting `SqlBulkCopy` into any ambient transaction is a great idea unless your particular scenario absolutely demands it.

```
public static void BulkInsert<T>(PandaDataContext db, IList<T> list)
{
    var mustOpen = db.Database.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open;
    try
    {
        if (mustOpen)
            db.Database.Connection.Open();
        using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy((db.Database.Connection) as SqlConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default))
        {
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (mustOpen)
            db.Database.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks, the close is a good suggestion.  The only thing in the ambient transaction is be removing rows that the bulkcopy is replacing.

Comment: I would remove the rows independently (in a different transaction) to the sqlbulkcopy if that will not cause corrupt or invalid data. If you must have both in the same transaction, do a lot of testing with real volumes of data, and make sure it's stable and correct.

Comment: I need it in a transaction to make sure that nothing reads the data in-between it being cleared and replaced.  It seems performant enough, there's less than a million rows and blocking for 2 seconds doesn't matter.  Why do you have doubts about the sqlBulkCopy in the transaction?

Comment: I have found that with very large transactions that it can fail. You will need to test. I have typically found that doing tranches of data works better than trying to add millions of rows in a single transaction. You will just need to try it for your data loads and test.